# Sharepoint 2010 Search Server not crawling content due to filter daemon timeout?

Tags: search, sharepoint-enterprise, crawling

We recently did a Content Database refresh in our Test environment and am now finding that Search is not working.  We are using Sharepoint 2010 Search Server and all has been running fine until the latest refresh and now the Search is failing with the error message:

> The filter daemon did not respond within the timeout limit.

Nothing has changed that I can find, accounts and permissions are all the same and have not changed.  The sts4 site is found and crawled but not the http site, in content sources I have the http site set up, and this worked until the latest refresh.  In some ways, because the content database is so large, I am wondering if maybe the size is an issue and that is slowing down the crawl somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the problem here was completely unrelated to the Filter Daemon, we ended up having many User Accounts created under the HOME group.  This pushed the limits of the ACL beyond its 64k limit, and since we have trimming going on each time a page was being crawled it was checked against EVERY user in the list.  Due to the large number, we have 65,000+ Users, the crawl would time out.  Once the Users were removed so we only had the All Authenticated Users group listed the time outs stopped and the Crawls began completing, actually much faster than before.

A similar problem was resolved [over here](http://www.sweendog.net/blogengine/post/2012/02/03/The-Filter-Daemon-has-Timed-Out.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Could you please increase Search Time-out Setting, then check the effect.

For more information about Configure search time-out settings, check the following articles:

Configure search time-out settings (SharePoint 2010)
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee808862.aspx

Comment: We have done that, from 120 seconds to 360 seconds but there was no effect.  The crawler never gets anywhere from the root of the site, seems like the Filter Daemon error causes it to error out immediately without anything in the ULS logs.

Comment: Could you please paste the complete ULS logs?

Comment: There is nothing in the logs for Search at the time that is an error, what would you expect to see?  And the Filter Daemon timeout is what is displayed in the Crawl Log in the Search Application, I have never been able to find where that information is stored.

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem some time ago. I've never figured out the root cause for that but I was able to get search up and running by simple remove and re-attach the content DB. Don't ask me why, but it worked afterwards.

Comment: I wish that would work, we have redeployed the content database at least twice and still nothing.  Thanks for at least verifying that we are not the only ones seeing this.